# Angular 2 typescript 1.8 compliation error for loop statement

Tags: loops, typescript, angular

I want to loop on an array .

There is my code:

```
@Input()
applicationLinks: ApplicationLink[];


applicationRows: ApplicationLinkRow[];
for(applicationLink in applicationLinks) {
    applicationRows.push(applicationLink);
}
```

in gives a compilation error

> (= expected).

i had try also

```
for(applicationLink of applicationLinks)
for(var applicationLink in applicationLinks)
for(var applicationLink of applicationLinks)
```

Each time gives a compilation error !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move this code into a method or the constructor

```
for(applicationLink in applicationLinks) {
    applicationRows.push(applicationLink);
}
```

should be something like:

```
class SomeClass {
  @Input()
  applicationLinks: ApplicationLink[];


  applicationRows: ApplicationLinkRow[];

  someMethod() {
    for(applicationLink in applicationLinks) {
        applicationRows.push(applicationLink);
    }
  }
}
```